# use java to download s3 object, given bucket endpoint, without bucket name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using java code upload/download files from s3 bucket.

I have a route53 CNAME (canonical name) pointing to s3 bucket endpoint (like cname.xyz.com -> bucketname.amazonaws.com

I need to download an object without giving bucket name in code, so that without updating code, one can update s3 bucket where objects are uploaded by repointing CNAME.

My question is, can java code access s3 bucket without giving bucket name, and only with endpoint provided?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you can't just parse the URL?

Comment: Why not just do a simple HTTP GET?

Comment: You cannot use use the Java V1 or V2 SDK without specifying the bucket name and key. Both require a Request object where you specify both of these values.

Comment: You can always retrieve the DNS record and extract the bucket name from it, but  if your goal is to avoid code changes, then use a standard configuration mechanism such as environment variables or Parameter Store.

Comment: "I have a route53 CNAME (canonical name) pointing to s3 bucket endpoint (like cname.xyz.com -> bucketname.amazonaws.com" This is a weird thing to do anyway.  If you connect to `cname.xyz.com` you'll get a cert that matches `*.amazonaws.com` and SSL verification will break.